# What is Azure Stack Time Server?

Tags: azure, azure-stack

Unable to find online that what is `Azure Stack Time Server`. All the related articles/posts I've found so far mention setting up the IP address (or something of that sort) for Azure Stack Time Server. But what actually is `Azure Stack Time Server`? Could someone please explain and/or point me to some online reference etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The Azure stack Time server is a time server that Stack uses to sync it's time. For a deployment with access to the internet, you can give the IP Address of any public time server. If it is an unconnected deployment, you will need to give a reachable address of an internal time server. Without a time server, Stack will not deploy successfully.

Comment: You can get current time server  details by connecting Pssession and run below command,
Get-AzureStackStampInformation